# file watching in a directory using perl

Tags: perl, file-watcher

i need to watch files that fall under a directory.I have coded the below script in perl . but it is not doing what i want .

1. whenever a file or files arrives , it has to do a movement .
2. And then it has to keep watching files again.
3. the script should be running in background.

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use warnings;
   use File::Copy qw(move);
   $src_dir = '/root/prasanna/dir';
   $tgt_dir = '/root/prasanna/dir/dir1';
   while (true) {
       opendir( DIR, "/root/prasanna/dir" )
           or die "Cannot open  /root/prasanna/dir: $!\n";
       my @Dircontent = readdir DIR;
       close DIR;
       my $items = @Dircontent;
       if ( $items > 2 ) {
           print "files available";
           while ($items) {
               print $items;
               move $src_dir. '/' . $items, $tgt_dir . '/' . $items;
               unlink $items;
           }
       }
       else { sleep 50; }
   }
   ```

The problem with the above code is 
1. the if statement keeps on printing the 'files available' . goes on infinite loop , it doesnt watch for files again .even if i do operations on file, i dont knw how to make it look for files again.
2. the script doesnt run in background .

any help is highly appreciated . thanks beforehand.!

Comment: Please format the code to improve readability.

Comment: I've just tried to reformat/fix your code - what you've pasted there. It's a) incompleted, and b) issue warnings. Fix warnings, turn on `use strict` and format your code and you'll get much better answers.

Comment: @joeblade im not able to edit in a way to put the code in separate lines. it shows error then.

Comment: I've applied an edit to fix formatting. I've had to add a trailing bracket, because one was missing. Please can you check that code as edited is what you've got?

Comment: looking much better :) thanks @Sobrique

Answer (score 0):

presuming you are running under Linux, use Linux::Inotify2...

```
use Linux::Inotify2;

# create an Inotify object
my $Inotify = Linux::Inotify2->new() or die "Fail: $!";

# choose which operations for which you wish to be notified
my $watchme = IN_CLOSE_WRITE | IN_CREATE | IN_MOVED_TO; # defined and exported

$Inotify->watch('/root/prasanna/dir', $watchme, \&watcher) or die "Fail: $!";

while (1) {
    $Inotify->poll;
}

sub watcher
{
  # do something here
}
```

Note it can only monitor local filesystems (i.e. no NFS mounts)